# Use words from list in regex in IF-statement

Tags: python, regex, list, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out a way to loop through a list in one line to use in a regular expression.

The following works almost like I want to, when going through a large text file:

```
for line in x1:
    For item in Feature_Type:
        if re.findall("(?i)^"+ item, line):
            active_feature_type = re.findall("(?i)^"+ item, line)
```

I have a list with a number of words:

```
Feature_Type = ["New feature", "Resolved feature", "Electrical feature",...]
```

The problem is that I'd somehow actually need to fuse the first "For" and "If"-statement into just an "If"-statement to continue with a number of else statements after this, some of them similar to this one, if possible.

Comment: Do you mean `any(re.findall("(?i)^"+ item, line) for item in Feature_Types)`? Or `next(...)` if you need the value.

Comment: So you want to check if [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) feature type is present on a line? Also I don't see the point of using regexes here. Just do `line.lower().startswith(feature)`... If you want to use regexes you should really just build one regex that matches all 4 feature names.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking? Why do you need the for loop opposed to a single regex split with pipes?

Comment: @a_guest that first worked, thanks! I completely failed at that logic.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments below my question, the following solved it:

```
any(re.findall("(?i)^"+ item, line) for item in Feature_Type)
```

After this I just saved the "line" itself and if would have contained additional text, then I'd just have filtered that out.